# AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance

Tags: python, azure, azure-ad-b2c, streamlit, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm try connect with custom policy of the AD B2C. However, i'm not successly. The tecnologies that used so: `streamlit`, `python`

I try the following code below:

```py
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_msal import Msal

auth_data = Msal.initialize_ui(
    client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>,                       
    authority="https://<TENANT>.b2clogin.com/<TENANT>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_CUSTOM_POLICY",
    scopes=[],
    connecting_label="Conectado",
    disconnected_label="Desconectado",
    sign_in_label="Entrar",
    sign_out_label="Desconectar"    
)
```

This is error:

```json
{
correlation_id: "a0a60245-7256-4689-aa63-5af9481f928e"
error: "invalid_instance"
error_codes: [50049]
error_description: "AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance. Trace ID: 5814ee67-0522-45df-b09e-004d74d89100 Correlation ID: a0a60245-7256-4689-aa63-5af9481f928e Timestamp: 2024-01-30 12:53:25Z"
error_uri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50049"
timestamp: "2024-01-30 12:53:25Z"
trace_id: "5814ee67-0522-45df-b09e-004d74d89100"
}
```

Comment: Please include the error-message you are getting

Comment: I Inclused the error on the description